# Is there a way to skip loading certain config files in sails.js app?

Tags: javascript, sails.js

Is there a way to put .js files in the sails.js  /config directory and instruct sails to skip them? i.e. NOT automatically load them when lifting?

I want to utilize the sails.js *config.custom* features. However, my app has a tremendous number of custom settings so I want to split them into separate files (i.e. custom1.js, custom2.js, etc) However, I need the custom settings loaded in a specific order because the settings refer to each other and because code being executed as the settings are created.

What I was thinking was using the custom.js file to load my settings modules as needed so I can control how it is built. Maybe do something like this:

```
let customSettings1 = require('./custom1.js');
let customSettings2 = require('./custom2.js');
let settings = {
    cust1:customSettings1,
    cust2:customSettings2
}
module.exports.custom = settings;
```

However this approach means I need to instruct sails.js to ignore my subset custom modules because custom1.js will be loaded automatically once it exists in the /config folder. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot stop Sails from loading certain files, however there is still a solution.

Based on additional research and @nathanhawks answer it does appear Sails.js will automatically load any .js files in the /config folder & subfolders...there is no way to tell Sails to skip anything. However, it *will* skip extensions it doesn't recognize so this offers an opportunity to still use the /config folder but control what you're loading. Here's what I did:

/config/custom.js <- this file has my logic for loading all my own custom config files
/config/custom/settings1.config <- this is a regular module file, just renamed with extension ".config" and put in a subfolder called "custom". You can divide up your settings into as many files as needed. Because Sails.js doesn't recognize .config it skips during the automatic load of the config files. However, it will load your main custom.js file and this is where you can load the .config files on your own.

In custom.js you can do this:

```js
let set1 = require('./custom/settings1.config');
let set2 = require('./custom/settings2.config');
let set3 = require('./custom/settings3.config');

let mySettings = {
   mySettings1 : set1,
   mySettings2 : set2,
   mySettings3 : set3,
   myFunction : function() {
      // can add custom functions to your custom config object, like special getter/setters or anything else
   }
}
module.exports = mySettings;
```

Answer (score 0):

No. If they're in the `config` folder or any subfolder, they will be loaded. However, once you've put them in a new folder, you can conditionally require them in your `config/custom.js` logic.

If sails isn't woken-up enough yet (during config-loading) to accommodate your logic, you can set the config vars at any time:

```
sails.config.custom.test = 'wut';
console.log(sails.config.custom.test);
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming, after multiple attempts I've concluded that as well but did find that it'll only include files based on specific extensions. So I came up with a working solution I'll post in another comment.